# Duplicated results per row

Tags: php, mysql

I run a query, the result is good, but while putting into PHP result, the resuts are duplicated per row, here is the code:

```
$selectSi = 'SELECT * FROM series LEFT JOIN series_join on series.ids = series_join.id_sil GROUP BY series.ids';
$querySi = $connexion->query($selectSi);
$resultSi = $querySi->fetchAll();

$displaying = 5;
// building table here


foreach($resultSi as $siK=>$siV)
            {
                $ids = $siV['ids'];
                $silsila_en = $siV['silsila_en'];
                $id_shks = $siV['id_shks'];


    // get singer
    $sSel = 'SELECT shk_fname, shk_lname, shk_tran FROM shk_tbl WHERE id_shk = "'.$id_shks.'"'; 
    $sReq = $connexion->query($sSel);
    $sRes = $sReq->fetchAll();

    $listShk = '';

    foreach($sRes as $vS)
    {
        $shk_fname = $vS['shk_fname'];
        $shk_lname = $vS['shk_lname'];


        $shkFullName = $shk_fname.' '.$shk_lname;

        $shkFullNameLink = '<a href="">';
        $shkFullNameLink .= $shkFullName;
        $shkFullNameLink .= '</a> - ';

        $listShk .= $shkFullNameLink;

        $listSheikhs = substr($listShk, 0,-2).'<br />';

    }

// putting result into a table

echo '<tr class="multiColor">';
echo '<td>'.$silsila_en.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$listSheikhs.'<br /></td>';

echo '</tr>';
            }
echo '</table>';
```

and the tables are like this

**PS: Instead of numbers result, it is singers name**

[image: serie table]

[image: serie_dup table]

I am looking for a result like:

Conciseness of speech: 114 - 136
The eternal journey:  325 - 326 - 327
Night Mare:  303 - 332 - 331 - 330 - 329 - 328 - 282 - 306 - 281 - 126 - 120

but I am getting something like:

Conciseness of speech: 114 - 136
The eternal journey:  114 - 136 - 325 - 326 - 327
Night Mare:  114 - 136 - 325 - 326 - 327 - 303 - 332 - 331 - 330 - 329 - 328 - 282 - 306 - 281 - 126 - 120

so the first row is duplicated to second, and second is duplicated to third

Thanks in advance

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: What is the output, and what is the expected output?

Comment: You're getting duplicates because you have created a Cartesian join. To get rid of this you need to do an outer join. http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/joins/

Comment: As a note, screenshots of data aren't very useful, especially when they contain a lot of irrelevant information. Try to keep your questions short and concise.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard: how to do so?

Comment: Maybe you didn't post all your code, but you are using a loop `foreach($resS as $S){` and in that loop you don't even use the value `$S` so that would generate exact duplicates if it is run more than once.

Comment: Change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: I changed to LEFT JOIN but still the same result, however I added to my query a GROUP BY silsila_en

Comment: The code in your post is not the code that gives this result. I appreciate you edited it for brevity, but evidently you made changes that hide the problem. The most probably issue is that in your actual code you do not reset $listSingers in the outer loop. Maybe just a typo...

Comment: I edited my code but still results are duplicated